# Run conditional logic for apple/iOS devices in Cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-5.0.0

I am using Cordova 5 for a mobile app - I have a template that needs some text only showing if the app is run on a iOS device

What is the best way to do this with a frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the cordova plugin [cordova-plugin-device](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device) or it's adaptation on ngCordova : http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/device/

You can is with ngCordova device installed the following function

```
 if (ionic.Platform.isIOS())
```

Comment: **In addition:** [Here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/) can you find all the possible methods for `ionic`.